# ImportXML with XPath does not return an entry of a table

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, importxml

Using Google Sheets with `IMPORTXML` to scrape a piece of information from a website via `XPath`.

[Here's the site (click here).](https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/keyStatistics.jhtml?stockspage=keyStatistics&symbols=aapl)

The specific piece of information I'm trying to extract is the **Price/Sales (TTM)** number, i.e., **2.97**

Here's the XPath (I've tested it using the Google Chrome Extensions *XPath Helper* and *XPather*. It works.):

```
//div[@id='audit-integrity'][1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]
```

Here's my Google Finance function:

```
=IMPORTXML( "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/keyStatistics.jhtml?stockspage=keyStatistics&symbols=aapl" , "//div[@id='audit-integrity'][1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]")
```

The function doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `<tbody>`. There is no `<tbody>` in the HTML source. Browser puts it there (on its own; nothing to do with JavaScript on the page) because it believes it should be there, according to HTML spec.

Just remove `/tbody` from the path:

```
=IMPORTXML( "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/keyStatistics.jhtml?stockspage=keyStatistics&symbols=aapl" , "//div[@id='audit-integrity'][1]/table/tr[10]/td[2]")
```

And in general: when XPath doesn't work, debug by removing all of the selectors, then adding one by one until the formula breaks...

Comment: Incredibly helpful thanks! To add a bit more detail for Chrome users: Chrome DevTools ("Inspect" on right-click) appears to add `<tbody>`, when it's not originally present. "View Source" on right-click does not appear to add it. Another wrinkle is that `tbody` is also included in the path when you "Copy... XPath" via Inspect in Chrome DevTools.