# How to Determine the Xpath Query to a Datapoint in a Table for Use with IMPORTXML?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, importxml

I'm looking to retrieve the most recent financial figure for a single data point from a table using IMPORTXML.

[The target page](https://www.google.com/finance?q=GOOG&fstype=ii) displays three sets of financial figures for a company on quarterly and annual bases.  In this case, I only want the "Total Debt" figure listed from the balance sheet for whatever is the most recent fiscal period available.

I've used the following IMPORTXML formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=GOOG&fstype=ii","//td[contains(.,'Total Debt')]")
```

This results in only the data label displayed vertically in two adjacent cells.

```
Total Debt
Total Debt
```

I've also used this IMPORTXML formula with the Xpath query determined using Chrome:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=GOOG&fstype=ii","//*[@id='fs-table']/tbody/tr[27]/td[2]")
```

This results in four values (data from two financial statements for two periods each) displayed vertically, as below, in adjacent cells with the third value down being correct.  Per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82399/importxml-with-xpath-does-not-return-an-entry-of-a-table) to another discussion, I've tried removing the "tbody" element node resulting in an "#N/A" error:  "Imported content is empty."

```
4,207.00
15,826.00
5,208.00
5,220.00
```

For now, I'm trying to avoid using IMPORTHTML and INDEX for parsing a whole table since I need only a single value from the table.

How do I determine the Xpath query for this page to retrieve (1) the "Total Debt" figure for (2) always the most recent reporting period?

EDIT:  Because there are two elements with same name, "Total Debt," I had also tried using the below formula with and without predicates (appending 1, 2, [last], etc. in square brackets) and got returned an error with empty content.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=GOOG&fstype=ii","//*[local-name() = 'Total Debt'][1]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

AFAIK, regarding XPath queries to be used with IMPORTXML there isn't straightforward method as XPath 1.0 support looks that was not fully implemented and the web pages developers could follow the practices to set the structure of their webpages.

### Explanation

While the use of tools like Chrome Developer Tools or browser extensions/add-ons could be helpful sometimes these tools doesn't return a XPath query that could be used by IMPORTXML due to differences on how XPath support was implemented by the developers of each tool, by the other hand, web pages could comply or not with the XML rules, so to find the XPath query to be used with IMPORTXML could be necessary to analyze the structure of the source web page and to do several tries.

## XPath queries for the use case

The below XPath queries returns `5,208.00`

1.

```
//div[@id="balinterimdiv"]//tr[contains(.,'Total Debt')]/td[2]
```

2.

```
(//tr[contains(.,'Total Debt')]/td[2])[1]
```

### Explanation

The referred page includes two views for the Balance Sheet: Quarterly Data and Annual Data. Both of them looks to have the same structure as both includes a table cell (td tag) with the text `Total Debt`. Fortunately, each view are inside a div tag and each of them have their own id, so in order to get only one, the first step in the XPath query could be to select the right view, then the second step could be to select the right table row (tr tag) and the third step to select the right table cell (td tag).

Another approach is to use the construct `(xpath_query)[position() = 1]` (see the reference).

## References

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295136/1595451) by [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) to [What is the XPath expression to find only the first occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294997/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-find-only-the-first-occurrence) referred by [Dale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/22565/dale) in a comment to another answer to the question in this thread.

Comment: This works great for selecting the correct value for either period specified.  In order to select the most current figure, I assumed I can reference the top row's second column's elements in both div's tables to evaluate.  This would require two additional queries (the date for each period) and one or two Google Spreadsheets functions wrapped in an IF function.  Do you think there's a more elegant way to accomplish same with IMPORTXML and the current page's XML or will I have to use Google Apps Script to efficiently accomplish same?  I'm happy to make this a separate question.

Comment: @Catalyx :  Did you already consideres to use rhe built-in function GOOGLEFINANCE? In any case posting a new question is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I use GOOGLEFINANCE functions frequently.  Its limitation at this time is that it's primary for actively traded market instruments such as stocks, mutual funds and currencies.  I'll post the question separately.  Thanks.

Comment: It appears that the URL (Google Finance site) already provides the most recent figures in the interim div for all companies I checked.  FYI, unless the data are manually calculated and input, some of these interim figures may not be reliable under certain scenarios.  There are further potential problems using the cash flow statements.  The page however seems "good enough" though as a source.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, assuming the page is rendered is to use a plugin or add-on to generate it for you.  For example, if you use Firefox use this link.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/

or this using Firebug which is another add-on with this

http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had used Firebug, which generated an unusually long query that didn't work so I reverted to Chrome.  I believe the issue is with namespaces since there are two elements (for quarter and annual figures respectively) with same name "Total Debt."

Comment: You can tell your xPath to use the first element.  I believe you put a [1] after the path.  Check out a similar question referenced here on stackoverflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294997/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-find-only-the-first-occurrence

Comment: The second formula above uses predicates and adding another ([3] to retrieve the third value) gives an "empty" error.  Similar goes for the first formula.

Comment: Can you get the object before it?

Comment: Yes in both formulas.

Comment: I don't see Total Debt on the sheet when I open https://www.google.com/finance?q=GOOG&fstype=ii

Comment: Click at top the "Balance Sheet" link and it will appear in the table's left column in the 27th row.

Comment: Try this ->> .//*[@id='fs-table']/tbody/tr[27]/td[2]

Comment: I used FirePath to extract this.  Part of the problem is that you need to be on the right sheet (Balance Sheet) to get the value.

Comment: I used that XPath query in the second formula above that results in the four values returned vertically.  Appending numeric predicates with square brackets to select one of the four values only produced errors.