# Using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) with regex to extract website data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, regex

I'm trying to extract data from a list of >1000 URLs using a script that uses `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` and regex based on this [article](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/why-wont-importxml-work-on-this-sheet).

This is the code I'm using.

```
function importRegex(url, regex_string) {
  var html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regex_string.length) {
      var regex = new RegExp( regex_string, "i" );
      content = html.match(regex)[1];
    }
  }
  content = unescapeHTML(content);
  Utilities.sleep(1000); // avoid call limit by adding a delay
  return content;  
}

var htmlEntities = {
  cent:  '¢',
  pound: '£',
  yen:   '¥',
  euro:  '€',
  copy:  '©',
  reg:   '®',
  lt:    '<',
  gt:    '>',
  mdash: '–',
  quot:  '"',
  amp:   '&',
  apos:  '\''
};

function unescapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/\&([^;]+);/g, function (entity, entityCode) {
        var match;

        if (entityCode in htmlEntities) {
            return htmlEntities[entityCode];
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#x([\da-fA-F]+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match[1], 16));
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#(\d+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(~~match[1]);
        } else {
            return entity;
        }
    });
};
```

and the importregex function formula I'm using is

```
=importRegex(A4, "<h1 class=""ch-title"".*?>(.*)<\/h1>")
```

It gives the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null (line 9).
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, custom functions can't be used on >1000 of formulas in a single spreadsheet because Google Apps Script limits. You might improve the custom function to make it able to process a range (an array of values) but the execution time should not exceed 30 secs.

Second, regular expressions have several limitations to parse HTML. For details see [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/1595451)

Regarding the error message, it's very likely that the site that you trying to scrape has measures to prevent that.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that, I sort of figured out that regex has it's limits trying to scrap and that the site was blocking visits using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url), so I have a possible alternate solution using importxml, I've posted a different question in that regard at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293249/google-app-script-convert-macro-into-full-fledged-app-script