# Trying to fetch data from shopback.com.au with ImportXML function in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I am trying to fetch store name and cashback percentage from this website using google sheet's importxml function.

Put following commands with no success. Please help

`=importxml("https://www.shopback.com.au/all-stores", "//div[@class='store-list col-md-4 col-sm-6']")`

`=importxml("https://www.shopback.com.au/all-stores", "//div[@class='store-name']")`

`=importxml("https://www.shopback.com.au/all-stores", "//div[@class='store-cashback-value']")`

Comment: ERROR 1009 Access denied

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use `IMPORTXML` because the data you are trying to get is not included on the source code of the specified URL.

To ask for software recommendations post your question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Related

- [Google Sheets importxml() can't fetch from this URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/97491/88163)
- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)