# Google Sheets importxml() can't fetch from http://www.aastocks.com/

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I'm trying to fetch data using importxml() but it just fails with "#N/A".  I have tried it on other pages and works fine.  But it doesn't work on this site, and I don't know why.

Here is the formula that doesn't work:

`=importxml("http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/quick-quote.aspx?symbol=00027","//*[@id='tbQuote']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/span/span/text()")`

Ultimately I'm trying to fetch the "price change" (Chg), and "price change (%)" (Chg(%)) elements, but all fail.

What can I do to fetch these two pieces of data?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: That page isn't XML, at least that is the error that is shown if I try that snippet. You need something more elaborate as shown here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97588/45873

Comment: I see empty boxes for Chg and Chg(%)